# Zendesk API From Client Code

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

[I have set up JWT based authentication](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/218278138) so that my iOS and Android clients can submit tickets for a given user.

I see that the widgets are hitting: `https://<domain>.zendesk.com/api/mobile/requests.json`.

My question is, is this API documented? I would like to use the same API along with JWT basic auth from a web browser without having to use the zendesk supplied web widget.

The APIs that I see documented usually expect to be called on behalf of an agent and as such cannot be run in the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's an internal API, and as such the only documentation is in the javadocs or header docs on the client side.

The requests endpoints are designed for end-users. This is true for the ones under mobile and /api/v2. If you have an end user in a web application, then they will have access to the requests endpoints under api/v2.

Comment: I am looking at the various Auth options for the REST APIs https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction#security-and-authentication and I don't see any way to auth them using the same JWT mechanism that I use with the iOS/ Android widgets.

Comment: Hey Alex. Regular Zendesk JWT and mobile SDK JWT are two different concepts. You'll needs two endpoints.

Comment: So is there any way to perform api actions directly from the browser? And if so, how do I auth on behalf of the end user?